# Get gps location by scraping a website | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, gps, python-requests-html

In my python project I want to get my gps location.
So I've thought of parsing a website which gives me these information:
https://www.where-am-i.net/ works perfect!
So I wrote the following script for parsing out the Latitude, Longitude:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#website = "https://schlechtewitze.com/kurze-witze"
website = "https://www.where-am-i.net/"

source = requests.get(website).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_ = "location"):
    summary = div.p.text
    print(summary)
    print()
```

And it almost works, but only almost: It returns: *My location is: 0.0, 0.0*
As you can see, it returns not the true location, because my computer (windows 10) blocks the location request. For example when I open it in my browser:
[image: Asking for permission for getting the location (Sorry for the german)]

The location will only be shown after i clicked to *allow* (*Zulassen* in german) the website to get my computers location.

BUT in the script i can't "click this button".

Question Result:
**How can I allow the website to get my location via the script** (beautiful soup, requests)?

*(I would not mind if there is another solution (without bs4) to get my GPS location)*

Comment: you'll need to make the same requests that the button does

Comment: And how can i do this?

Comment: you'll have to figure out what the request is via developer tools of the browser and then replicate with python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MukundKulkarni mentioned there's this tutorial, which uses Selenium, to parse a website:
[How I Understood: Getting accurate current geolocation using Python Web-scraping and Selenium](https://codeburst.io/how-i-understood-getting-accurate-geolocation-using-python-web-scraping-and-selenium-7967d721587a)

Obviously they don't have to allow the location tracking first. I'll use Selenium for further web-scraping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **geocoder** instead

Simply do,

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(g.latlng)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. geocoder uses IP to get the location. I've done a few examples for this. But the location it returns is hundreds kilometres away. I have to use GPS.

Comment: Okay sorry about that, then this would be a better solution https://codeburst.io/how-i-understood-getting-accurate-geolocation-using-python-web-scraping-and-selenium-7967d721587a

Comment: I will work on it, thanks! But maybe there will be a solution here so I won't delete the question